# Debo clickear dos veces para que la funcion OnClick funcione correctamente

Tags: javascript, html5, function, div, onclick

Tengo un problema al usar el evento OnClick, la función lo que hace es abrir y cerrar un div al hacer click en una imagen, el problema es que al cargar la página debo clickear dos veces la imagen para que empiece a funcionar correctamente esta función.

Pasa lo siguiente:
Cargo la pagina, hago click dos veces en la imagen y ahí recién aparece el div, luego a partir de ahí funciona correctamente, es decir, con 1 solo click ya abre y cierra, el problema es al principio.

Les dejo el código

HTML:

```
<div class="menulateral" id="menulat" display="none">
    <script src="home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
<div class="perfilhome">
    <img src="perfilprueba.jpg" alt="" class="fotoperfil" onclick="abrircerrar()">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function abrircerrar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menulat");
    if(x.style.display=="none") {
        x.style.display="block";
    } else {
        x.style.display="none"
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema te ocurre porque la primera vez que ejecutas la función abrircerrar, x.style.display no es "none", entonces se cumple el else y se establece a "none" luego cuando vuelves a ejecutar si que es "none" porque lo pusiste en el else y se establece a "block". Mira el valor original de x.style.display por ejemplo en la consola y cambia el if para que (x.style.display =="none" || x.style.display == "[lo que sea que esté por defecto]")

Comment: @track3r Muchas gracias! lo que tuve que cambiar fue lo siguiente: antes lo que tenia era <div class="menulateral" id="menulat" display:none> y lo que me di cuenta es que al hacer click esta funcion cambiaba a <div class="menulateral" id="menulat" style="display: none">, entonces lo que hice fue dejar directamente <div class="menulateral" id="menulat" style="display: none"> y listo, gracias!

Comment: Hola. Por favor incluye en tu pregunta el bloque html **como lo tenías antes de resolverlo**. Y agrega una respuesta indicando la solución que encontraste. Eso será de ayuda para personas que tengan problemas similares.

Comment: Te cedo ese honor @quevedo o si quieres tu mismo Gonzalo Ramirez.

Answer (score 2):

Como ya te dijeron en comentarios, el atributo `display="none"` es incorrecto, debiendo ser `style="display:none;"`. Me tomé la libertad de hacer algunas modificaciones para sugerir el uso de buenas prácticas:

- No incluyas eventos dentro de las etiquetas HTML, porque puede complicar el mantenimiento del código; en su lugar, agrega un "escuchador" a cada elemento, ya sea por ID o por clase.
- Permite que la función reciba un parámetro y que se pueda usar para mostrar u ocultar cualquier elemento.
- Define nombre de ID y clase de forma que sean fáciles de leer, por ejemplo:

  - .menulateral - .menu-lateral o .menuLateral
  - #menulat - #menu-lateral o #menuLateral
  - .fotoperfil - .foto-perfil o .fotoPerfil; si este es único, entonces debería ser ID en vez de clase
- Lo mismo en javascript, define nombres de variables y funciones fáciles de leer:

  - abrircerrar() - abrirCerrar()
  - En lugar de declarar una variable `x` usa alguna que te de una idea del tipo de contenido que vas a manipular, como `item` o `element`
- Agregué otro ejemplo para poder mostrar u ocultar con solo cambiar la clase CSS y sin tener que analizar previamente el estilo; el método `toggle()` agrega o elimina la clase especificada. [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
// Definir variables de elementos que se van a modificar
let menuLateral = document.querySelector('#menu-lateral');
let menuClass = document.querySelector('#prueba2');

// Recibir parámetro, así se puede usar para mostrar u ocultar cualquier elemento
function abrirCerrar(item) {
    if(item.style.display=="none") {
        item.style.display="block";
    } else {
        item.style.display="none"
    }
}

function mostrarOcultar(item) {
    item.classList.toggle('mostrar');
}

// Escuchar clics en "foto de perfil" (por clase)
document.querySelector('.foto-perfil').addEventListener('click', () => abrirCerrar(menuLateral));
// Escuchar clics en botón (por ID)
document.querySelector('#con-clase').addEventListener('click', () => mostrarOcultar(menuClass));
```

```css
/* Estado inicial: Oculto */
.menu-oculto {
    display:none;
}
/* Mostrar al agregar clase */
.mostrar {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Usando atributo de estilo directamente en la etiqueta</h2>
<div class="menul-ateral" id="menu-lateral" style="display:none;">
    Contenido del menú lateral
</div>
<div class="perfi-lhome">
    <button class="foto-perfil">Mostrar / Ocultar</button>
</div>
<h2>Mostrar u ocultar mediante clases CSS</h2>
<div class="menu-oculto" id="prueba2">
    Contenido del elemento oculto
</div>
<button id="con-clase">Mostrar / Ocultar</button>
```